# When looping through an array, is there a way to avoid doing a comparison upon each loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

Assuming a loop that invariably iterates one at a time through some sequence, I want to know if there is **some clever loop structure or trick that avoids doing a check upon each iteration for the end of the array**.

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) { 
    //something 
}
```

or

```
int i=0;
while (i<length) { 
    //something 
    i++;
}
```

For clarification, I'm referring to comparisons like those in the above examples `(i<length)`.

If relevant, I generally code in C++, but am open to hearing about other languages that provide ways around this.

Comment: Sure, it's called [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) and many compilers do it automatically

Comment: `for(;;){/* something */}`, of course =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can unroll the loop like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < length - 3; i += 4) { // 4x unrolled loop
    //something(i)
    //something(i+1)
    //something(i+2)
    //something(i+3)
}
for ( ; i < length; i++) {           // clean up loop for residual 0..3 iterations
    //something(i)
}
```

Comment: Manually unrolling the loop would make it more difficult for the compiler to do its own (probably more optimized) unrolling, correct?

Comment: @sgarza62: if you know what you're doing then manual unrolling can sometimes be more efficient than letting the compiler do it, but this kind of thing is usually a last resort and should never normally be done manually unless you are sure the loop is a bottleneck. You also need to benchmark and make sure that your unrolled version is better than the compiler's.

Answer (score 1):

You can unroll the loop:

```
int length = 20 ;
int i=0;
while (i+3<length) { 
    //something 
    i++;
    //something 
    i++;
    //something 
    i++;
    //something 
    i++;
}

//handle any remaining cases
while (i<length) { 
    //something 
    i++ ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there is some clever loop structure or trick that avoids doing a check upon each iteration for the end of the array.

Set i to the length, then decrement i on each iteration of the loop.

```
int i = length;
while ( i-- >= 0) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: You've found a loophole in the phrasing on the question, but not in the spirit of it

Comment: Are you saying a check against 0 is somehow internally faster than a check against non-zero integers?

Comment: it does this "avoids doing a check upon each iteration for the end of the array."